# Drag DIV and Drag Resize in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to make it possible to drag my divs on the screen and be also able to resize the divs by dragging the bottom-right corner of a resizable div.  It works great in Chrome if I use:

```
$('div').draggable();
```

But FireFox will not resize.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

If I remove the jQuery - draggable command the resize works great in FireFox, however...

TIA

DK

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery resizable then that might be your problem.

```
$( "div" ).resizable();
```

Comment: I do not use `$( "div" ).resizable();` and it works fine in Chrome, but not in FireFox...

Comment: I cant comment on why it works in chrome but not ff, but I believe that draggable is a widget to drag an item(div or what not), and resizable is a widget to resize it, try it out and see if it works would be my first thought.

Comment: I have included and tested your resizable code and it does not work.  Firefox treats the bottom-right triangle as a zone for dragging.

Comment: keep in mind that the resizable feature can be triggered with CSS instruction  `resize:both;`

Comment: It is hard to say only being able to see one line of code you supplied, but it seems like something else is going on here. Look at this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zM9uw/, a div that is just draggable should not be resizable in crome, and a box that is resizable should work in any of the big browsers.  I have a feeling you have done something in css to alter the normal states of these "widget".  have you done anything to the z-index of the div in question or its surrounding elements?  Because out of the box it should work as desired

Comment: I'll get to the bottom of this...  Thanks for persisting...  I should be able to work it out from here...

Comment: I did use the `resize:both` in CSS ,but with or without it does not work...  However, I will start the dive from yours and work my way back.  I accepted your answer...

Comment: After several tests, the reason you were successful is because Fiddle is wired somehow differently.  It does not work even in the simplest form with the jQuery resize...